# Wrapper around ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest framework for making network calls in my iOS applications. But I don't want to use it directly in all the controllers in my application. So I thought of writing a layer around ASIHTTPRequest. My code use this layer to use ASIHTTPRequest. The benefit wil be in future I should be able to replace this framework with some other framework and my code will be unchanged just the layer would change. I want to know what should be the strategy to do so. Should I subclass my class from ASIHTTPRequest class, or implement my own class. What should be the method I should consider implementing.

Currently I am implementing it like this. 
My wrapper is

```
MyRequestHandler.h : NSObject       
@property ASIHTTPRequest *asiHttpReq;    

-(void) sendAsyncGetRequest
{
    self.asiRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
    if(self.tag != 0){
        self.asiRequest.tag = self.tag;
    }
    [self.asiRequest setDelegate:self];
    [self.asiRequest startAsynchronous];        
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
     MyResponseObj *respone = <From request obj>
     if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)]){
            [delegate performSelector:@selector(requestFinished:) withObject:response];
        }
 }
```

And in my viewcontroller I would do this:

```
MyViewController.h : UIViewContoller
@property MyRequestHandler *reqHandler;

-(void) fireRequest
{
NSString* requestUrl = <create URL>;
if(requestUrl){

    // [self showLoadingIndicatorView];

    // Proceed for request.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl];
    reqHandler = [MyRequestHandler requestWithURL:url];
    reqHandler.tag = 1000;
    [reqHandler setDelegate:self];
    [reqHandler sendAsyncGetRequest];
}
}

- (void)requestFinished:(MyResponse*) responseData{
        // Do Your parsing n all here.
}

- (void)requestFailed:(MyResponse*) responseData{
        // Handle the error here.
}
```

Is this the right way to do it. The problem here is as I have created property of myrequesthandler in viewcontroller I can only make one request at a time, and loosing the capability of ASIHTTPRequest of making multiple request simultaneously.

Can you suggest me how to approach problems like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'm using:

```
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"

@interface RequestPerformer : NSObject {
    id localCopy; // to avoid exec_bad_access with arc
    ASIHTTPRequest *getRequest;
    ASIFormDataRequest *postRequest;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) SEL callback;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) SEL errorCallback;

- (void)performGetRequestWithString:(NSString *)string stringDictionary:(NSDictionary *)stringDictionary delegate:(id)requestDelegate requestSelector:(SEL)requestSelector errorSelector:(SEL)errorSelector;
- (void)performPostRequestWithString:(NSString *)string stringDictionary:(NSDictionary *)stringDictionary dataDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary delegate:(id)requestDelegate requestSelector:(SEL)requestSelector errorSelector:(SEL)errorSelector;

@end
```

//

```
#import "RequestPerformer.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"

@implementation RequestPerformer

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize callback, errorCallback;

- (void)performGetRequestWithString:(NSString *)string stringDictionary:(NSDictionary *)stringDictionary delegate:(id)requestDelegate requestSelector:(SEL)requestSelector errorSelector:(SEL)errorSelector {

    localCopy = self;

    self.delegate = requestDelegate;
    self.callback = requestSelector;
    self.errorCallback = errorSelector;

    NSMutableString *requestStringData = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if (stringDictionary)
        for (NSString *key in [stringDictionary allKeys])
            [requestStringData appendFormat:@"%@=%@&", key, [stringDictionary objectForKey:key]];
    NSString *resultString = [requestStringData substringToIndex:[requestStringData length]-1];

    getRequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", string, [resultString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]];
    [getRequest setDelegate:self];
    [getRequest setRequestMethod:@"GET"];

    //NSLog(@"request url = %@", [getRequest.url absoluteString]);
    [getRequest startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)performPostRequestWithString:(NSString *)string stringDictionary:(NSDictionary *)stringDictionary dataDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary delegate:(id)requestDelegate requestSelector:(SEL)requestSelector errorSelector:(SEL)errorSelector {

    localCopy = self;

    self.delegate = requestDelegate;
    self.callback = requestSelector;
    self.errorCallback = errorSelector;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

    postRequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [postRequest setDelegate:self];
    [postRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    if (stringDictionary)
        for (NSString *key in [stringDictionary allKeys])
            [postRequest setPostValue:[stringDictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];

    if (dataDictionary)
        for (NSString *key in [dataDictionary allKeys])
            [postRequest setData:[dataDictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];

    //NSLog(@"request url = %@", [postRequest.url absoluteString]);
    [postRequest startAsynchronous];
}

#pragma mark - ASIHTTPRequest Delegate Implementation

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)crequest {
    NSString *status = [crequest responseString];

    if (self.delegate && self.callback) {
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:self.callback])
            [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:self.callback withObject:status waitUntilDone:YES];
        else
            NSLog(@"No response from delegate");
    }
    localCopy = nil;
}
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)crequest {
    if (self.delegate && self.errorCallback) {
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:self.errorCallback])
            [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:self.errorCallback withObject:crequest.error waitUntilDone:YES];
        else
            NSLog(@"No response from delegate");
    }
    localCopy = nil;
}

@end
```

To use it, just import `RequestPerformer.h` in your `UIViewController` and do smth like:

```
[requestManager performGetRequestWithString:tempString stringDictionary:stringDictionary dataDictionary:dataDictionary delegate:self requestSelector:@selector(requestSucceeded:) errorSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
```

Parameters:

- `(NSString *)string` - url string, where to post your request;
- `(NSDictionary *)stringDictionary` - dictionary, which contains all the
  text information (such as name, id etc.);
- `(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary` - dictionary, which contains all data information (such as photos, files, etc.);
- `(id)requestDelegate` - delegate to perform selectors below;
- `(SEL)requestSelector` - selector, which will be executed while successfully request;
- `(SEL)errorSelector` - selector, which will be executed, while error occurred.

Comment: Hi Demon, The solution you have provided, more or less the same thing i am using. I have just given the bits of that here. In your wrapper also you can only make one request at a time because getRequest is a property of the class not a local variable of a function. If you try to make second request before the response of the first request getRequest object will be replaced with the second one and you would never get the response of first request. Where ASIHTTPRequest is derived from NSOperation and each request run in the NSOperation queue, you can fire multiple requests simultaneously.

Comment: In ASIHTTPRequest you can fire multiple requests like this, by creating a local variable which gets added to a NSOperationQueue, hence kept alive until the response comes back.       ASIHTTPRequest *req  = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        req.tag = MemberPrescriptionRequestTypeDrug;
        [req setDelegate:self];
        [req startAsynchronous];

Comment: This wrapper is aimed to perform just one request. If you need to perform more at the same time, you should to create another instance of 'RequestPerformer' with other dictionaries and callback-selectors (it's logical) and perform request from this instance.

Answer (score 0):

In above answer (demon9733), wrapper class has been created delegate property with retain. In general, delegate property should be assign to remove retain cycle.